# Cannot create folder remotely

Tags: powershell, directory

I cannot make a remote folder on one of the Domain PCs using PowerShell command.
The error I get says: *Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'path'.* I get this for the following code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ADCLIENT04 -Credential INTERNAL\Administrator NEW-ITEM -path c:\ -name logfiles -itemtype directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `-ScriptBlock` parameter:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ADCLIENT04 -Credential INTERNAL\Administrator -ScriptBlock  {
    NEW-ITEM -path c:\ -name logfiles -itemtype directory
}
```

Comment: @ArtūrasKalandarišvili mark it as answer in that case.